# How to use request.GET.get method to take agruments from url in django rest framework?

Tags: python, python-3.x, django-rest-framework

I want to created a non-model API using Django Rest Framework, that will take some parameter from url and calculate few results. As of now I have hardcoded the values in code itself, to make the framework working. But I want my model will take parameters from url.

I have tried using request.query_params and request.GET.get but I really don't know how it works.
My framework is not using any Model & Serializer

Also please guide how I can configure url for this.

Answer (score 0):

I have been able to find the answer from youtube. 
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qmxoGYCFruM&t=29s
Please let me know if I can do it in a better way!!